# Why API is getting called twice in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

So, I am trying to dispatch an action to all a get request. But I can see that the API is getting called twice but the action dispatched once. Please Help in this -

**Component**

```
const Login = (props: Props) => {
const { dispatch, } = props;

const onForgetPasswordButtonClick = (data: ForgetPasswordData) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'LOGINPAGE_FORGET_PASSWORD_REQUEST',
          payload: { data },
        });
     };

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { loading } = state.ui;
  return {
    loading
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login);
```

**Saga**

```
const forgetPasswordSaga = function* (action: Action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(forgetPassword, action.payload);
    yield put({ type: FORGET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS });
    Router.go(RoutePath.LOGIN);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: FORGET_PASSWORD_FAIL });
    yield put({ type: ERROR_SET, metadata: { message: Error.getErrorMessage(e) } });
  }
};

export default [
  takeLatest('LOGINPAGE_FORGET_PASSWORD_REQUEST', forgetPasswordSaga),
];
```

Comment: Maybe something from catch will be calling the api?

Comment: may be you are forking this saga twice, where you have register all sagas

Comment: I don't fully get you based on your snippet. I need to know when will you call this callback  `onForgetPasswordButtonClick` in your `Login` component. I'm aware of you seem to call reloading login path again `Router.go(RoutePath.LOGIN);`?

Comment: I did console.log() inside function onForgetPasswordButtonClick. But it trigger once only
Only the forgetPasswordSaga is getting trigger twice
@tmhao2005